# React components assembled with Webpack, where do I call React.render?

Tags: reactjs

I've been following the Thinking in React & the other tutorial on the React site, I've gone a bit further and split each component into it's own file, which I then assemble using Webpack.

My question is, if I load the webpacked javascript, where do I call React.render?

Answer (score 0):

Require whatever your top-level component is from another module (or create a module which defines a component which is responsible for using your other components - it's common to have an `App` component or similar for this) and render it there, e.g. using a component from Thinking With React:

```
var FilterableProductTable = require('./FilterableProductTable');

var PRODUCTS = [
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7'}
];

React.render(<FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />, document.body);
```

Point your webpack config at this module as your app's entry point, e.g. if you'd put the above code in `src/app.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app'
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I didn't think you could mix JSX stuff like that into normal js files? I've tried what you suggest but using index.jsx and that doesn't work either.

Comment: You will need to use babel-loader or jsx-loader in your webpack configuration. These loaders will precompile jsx into javascript, and then in your index.html, you include the compiled javascript bundle.

Comment: I have the jsx-loader installed & it's compiling the javascript bundle, which I am including in my index.html.